# javascript serialize json array with commas

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to apply this function [How parameterize array to as single comma separated value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20385239/how-parameterize-array-to-as-single-comma-separated-value) in a '*function called by its name*' script but it doesn't work as expected:

```
function add(a,b,c){
    return a+b+c
}

var vals = callFct("add", window, 2,3,4); 
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += "<br>Function result: "+vals
// result = Function result: 9 ----> 2+3+4 : OK
```

The values are coming from: `json={a:[2,3,4]}`

```
function serialize(vals){
    var output = [];
    for (var prop in vals) {
        if (vals.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
            output.push(vals[prop].join(','));
        }
    }
    return output;
}

var json = {a:[2,3,4]};
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += "<br>Used data:  "+serialize(json)
// result = Used data: 2,3,4 ---> seems to be OK... but

var test = callFct("add", window, serialize(json)); 
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += "<br>Function result:  "+test
// result = Function result : 2,3,4undefinedundefined ---> oups
```

I've tried to remove the 'undefined' ...

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += "<br>Function result :  "+test.replace(/undefined/g,'')
// result = Function result : 2,3,4 ---> nope
```

The called function:

```
function callFct(w, y, z ) {  
  var z = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
  console.log('vars = '+z)
  let v = w.split(".");
  let x = v.pop();
  for(var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
    y = y[v[i]];
  }
  return y[x].apply(y, z);
}
```

What's wrong in my way to proceed?

Comment: Why don't you use `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: The `json` variable is an object, not JSON (which is a text format), and `serialize` does not turn it into JSON. It turns it into an array of strings.

Comment: You'll need to show the code for `callFct` if you want help with that.

Comment: function added in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide better parameter names than `w`, `y`, and `z`...

If you change the names to the one's seen in the demo below, your return statement will look like the following:

> `return scope[last].apply(funcName, serialized);`

If you notice, you are calling apply on `window.add`. Make sure that method exists. I am not sure what `add` looks like, but it will take the "serialized" JSON data and the scope of the call will be the incoming string (first) parameter (which can apparently be dot-separated).

#### Notes

1. You can change this: `[...output, json[prop].join(',')]` to this: `output.concat(json[prop].join(','))` for browser compatability.
2. A "basic" polyfill for `flatMap` can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39838385/1762224

```js
const json = { a: [2, 3, 4] };

document.getElementById('result-1').innerHTML = 'Values: ' + serialize(json);

let sum = callFct('add', window, serialize(json));
document.getElementById('result-2').innerHTML = 'Sum: ' + sum;

let difference = callFct('subtract', window, serialize(json));
document.getElementById('result-3').innerHTML = 'Difference: ' + difference;

function serialize(json) {
  return Object.keys(json).reduce((output, prop) => {
    return [...output, json[prop].join(',')];
  }, []);
}

function callFct(funcName, scope, serialized) {
  serialized = Array.from(arguments).slice(2);
  console.log('vars = ' + serialized)
  const tokens = funcName.split('.');
  const last = tokens.pop();
  for (let i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    scope = scope[tokens[i]];
  }
  return scope[last].apply(funcName, serialized);
}

function prepareValues(serialized) {
  return serialized
    .flatMap(v => v.split(/,\s*/g))
    .map(v => parseInt(v, 10));
}

function add(serialized) {
  return prepareValues(serialized)
    .reduce((s, v) => s + v, 0);
}

function subtract(serialized) {
  return prepareValues(serialized)
    .reduce((s, v) => s - v);
}
```

```css
div[id^="result-"] { font-family: monospace; }
```

```html
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=Array.prototype.flatMap"></script>
<div id="result-1"></div>
<div id="result-2"></div>
<div id="result-3"></div>
```

Comment: it doesn't solve the prob: used data produced as explained in the question are right (2,3,4) but not in an exploitable format by function.

Comment: @Wolden OK, with your included function, that you provided after I originally answered, I tried to explain what is happening.

Comment: @Wolden I updated my `add` function to flat-map the results and then split the values. Your serialize is returning an array of "serialized" values. It is not a true string. You are building the results as an array of the joined values for each key.

Comment: yeeeeeeees thanks so much, it works perfectly :-)  ...btw, is there a "classical way" to replace flatMap which is not yet recognized by all browsers?

Comment: @Wolden you can create a polyfill. I will add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a simpliest solution:

```
// define empty vars
let a, b, c;    
const vars = [a, b, c];

// call function by its name
function callFct(fct) {  
  const toks = fct.split(".");
  const last = toks.pop();
  for(var i = 0; i < toks.length; i++) {
    window = window[toks[i]];
  }
  return window[last].apply(window, vars); // vars now in array
}

// functions to be called
function add(){
   return a+b+c
}
function substract(){
   return a-b-c
}  
function multiply(){
   return a*b*c
}

// produce real vars values
a = 20, b = 10, c = 5;

// get results
var add = callFct("add");
console.log(add); // 20+10+5 = 35

c = -5 // actualize any value
var subs = callFct("substract");
console.log(subs); // 20-10--5 = 15

var mult = callFct("multiply");
console.log(mult); // -1000

// mixing functions results
function mix(){
    return add/subs
}
var mixed = callFct("mix");
console.log(mixed); // 2.3333333333333335
```